# How to change line thickness for OpenGL shapes?

Tags: c++, opengl

Using OpenGL and C++, I can draw a shape but I want to make the line of the shape thicker. How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `glLineWidth(..)`

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLineWidth.xml

Comment: +1 for totally correct answer, though it should be used with some care. I rather use manually extruded quads, because I'm personally not able to figure out from the mess in the specs whether or not you can use glLineWidth, and how. Version 3.0 deprecates it and schedules for removal, 3.1 does not remove it, and later versions keep it at that. The main text in each spec says that width cannot be 0.0 or less, which makes perfect sense. At the same time, the small print in appendix E says values greater than 1.0 generate INVALID_VALUE, it doesn't explicitly say that it won't work, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
glLineWidth(n);
```

where `n` is the width of the line in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

```
glLineWidth(n);
```

is the function but sometimes it will have no effect because of the hardware acceleration. Use software rendering first.